# What is the selling price including VAT, if the VAT amounts to $€3.41$?

Tags: education

VAT rate is $8 \%.$ How I calculate the answer?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the vat rate is $0.08$ then the selling price *without* vat is given by $$S = 3.41/8 * 100 = 42.625$$

Then the overall price is given by $$P = 42.625 + 3.41 = 46.035$$ which rounded gives $46.04$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $x$ be the Price without VAT. Then its VAT is 
$$8\%\times x.$$
The actual VAT is known, so you can find $x$.

To find the actual selling price add $x$ and the VAT.

Comment: Could you open this formula to me? I've been thinking this but every time I get 42,625 what is not a correct answer.

Comment: I presume that you are missing the second step: I.e. summing the price without VAT to the VAT to get the actual price *with* VAT